# Change my javascript column to allow for every month gathered?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, google-visualization

Okay so I am gathering data from a database and using it to create a google visualization line chart. The user can select year intervals and a month. I have a json variable that gathers the data in an array. For example, if the user selects 1990-1992 and January, the json array variable will look like this:

```
[[1990,157894],[1991,173725],[1992,181227]]
```

Then I import the json variable into my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var inputData = [[1990,157894],[1991,173725],[1992,181227]] ;
var month = "January" ;

  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {    
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Year');
  data.addColumn('number', month);
  data.addRows(inputData);

    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({groupingSymbol: ',', fractionDigits: '0'});
    formatter.format(data, 1);  

    var options = {
      title: 'Unemployed Statistics',
      hAxis: {title: 'Year', format: '####'},
   vAxis: {title: 'Number of Unemployed'},
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

And from there I am able to create my graph. The issue comes when a user selects all months instead of one month. Say a user selects 1990-1992 and all months. Then the array will look like this:

[[1990,157894],[1990,161642],[1990,155422],[1990,146588],[1990,139732],[1990,131337],[1990,129894],[1990,139529],[1990,126164],[1990,124355],[1990,141208],[1990,146554],
[1990,141693],[1991,173725],[1991,189556],[1991,196588],[1991,157444],[1991,160583],[1991,160256],[1991,150932],[1991,144383],[1991,134035],[1991,136319],[1991,142753],[1991,152923],[1991,158291],[1992,181227],[1992,190536],[1992,183923],[1992,171126],[1992,180363],[1992,188129],[1992,180816],[1992,176638],[1992,165608],[1992,151023],[1992,158695],[1992,164348],[1992,174369]]

The first 1990 is January's value, 2nd is February, ... 13th is the annual average. See, there is no difference between each 1990 value. In reality though, January 1990 < February 1990 < December 1990. I don't need the annual average values. I guess my question is how do I go about changing the year values instead of all being the same (1990 for all) to now having different values based on the month (January 1990 < February 1990 < December 1990)?

Comment: Are you locked into using that data structure?  You can write javascript to parse that into an appropriate format, but you might want to consider revisiting the way you constructed that data array in the first place to transform it into something more friendly to work with.

Comment: How would I go about restructuring my json variable to allow for each month to have a different value?

Comment: You could change the JSON to be something like `[[1990,157894,1],[1990,161642,2],[1990,155422,3],[1990,146588,4],[1990,139732,5],[1990,131337,6],[1990,129894,7],[1990,139529,8],[1990,126164,9],[1990,124355,10],[1990,141208,11],[1990,146554,12], [1990,141693,-1]]` which adds a third attribute to each item representing the month, you could put "Average" as a string entry for the average which would enable you to identify these easily as it's NaN rather than the above which adds -1 instead. The provided code doesn't give enough details of the restrictions in data format required by your DataTable

Comment: I have now included my entire javascript portion. If I changed the JSON variable by adding a column like you suggested above, then how would I use that in my javascript file? What would I do with 1, 2, 3, ... -1 to use these to change my year values?

Comment: Before we get into the specifics of how to restructure the data, what is the output that you want?  Do you want a single line with points for every month/year combination, or do you want one line for each month, spanning across years?

Comment: Basically I want it to be similar to a stock market line chart. 1 total line, with each month to be represented as a new x axis interval (single line with points for every month/year combo).